# Calculating the padding of a XAML element as a percentage of its width

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to set the left and right padding of a `textbox` element in a XAML C# Windows Runtime app to be a percentage (10%) of the same element's width, so that when the element is resized along with the window, the padding changes to compensate. What is the best way to do this?

I've tried to do this by making a custom template for the `textbox` element and putting a grid with the correct column definitions inside the `ScrollViewer` along with a new `ContentPresenter` element. For some reason that I can't understand, however, moving the `name` attribute of the `ScrollViewer` to the newly created `ContentPresenter` causes a significant loss of performance. I would prefer if possible to use the default template if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a ValueConverter that takes in the element that you want to match your width to. Then in your Textbox, you would bind your padding to the element, using the ValueConverter.

Something like this:

```
public sealed class PercentageOfValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private const double DefaultValue = 150;
    private const double Percentage = 0.9;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        double result = 0;
        double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);

        if (result == double.NaN)
        {
            return DefaultValue; // Default value.
        }

        // Thickness gets assigned to the Padding property.
        return new Thickness(result * Percentage, 0, result * Percentage, 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you would use the converter by binding the padding of your text box to it. The converter is provided the Binding Path, which in this case, is the Grid.Width property. We can take that and return back 90% of that value as a Thickness object, which is then assigned to the padding property.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:PercentageOfValueConverter x:Key="PercentageOfValueConverter" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBox Padding="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, 
                    Converter={StaticResource PercentageOfValueConverter}, 
                    Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```